# Use condition in Elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I'd like to know if it's possible to use conditions when I define the mapping of an index, because depending on certain values of a field, other fields are then required.

For example :

```
PUT /my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "age": { "type": "integer" },  
      "email": { "type": "keyword" }, 
      "name": { "type": "text"  }, 
      "is_external": {"type": "boolean" }
      if [is_external] == true {
        "adress": { "type": "text" },
        "date": { "type": "date" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If there's no way to do this, how can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to do this kind of checks at the mapping level, because ultimately your index will contain both documents with `is_external: true` and `is_external: false` and so the mapping will have to also contain the `address` and `date` field definitions for the documents where `is_external: true` and there can only be one single mapping for each index.

If you want to enforce that a document with `is_external: true` also contains the `address` and `date` fields, then you can do this using an ingest pipeline [with a `drop` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/drop-processor.html):

```
...
{
  "drop": {
    "if" : "ctx.is_external == true && (ctx.date == null || ctx.address == null)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I understand that i should play with some processors of ingest pipeline.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! Let us know if you have any other questions